# Raspberry Pi - Interfacing HD44780 based 20x4 LCD via PCF8574 IOExpander

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

Thanks to ufux I got above setup working fine with Python. https://gist.github.com/ufux/6094977

However I would like the same to be implemented in C. I am pretty new to C programming. Could you guys help me get this done. I tried writing some C code. I used [wiringPi library](http://wiringpi.com/extensions/i2c-pcf8574/) since I thought it would be easier.

I'm unable to get it working. [Code I had written so far is here.](http://karunadheera.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/lcd_pcf8574.c)

Even I cannot get the LCD initialisation to work. Could anybody help me to get this working? Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

All issues fixed and the complete C based library for raspberry pi (to drive HD44780 via PCF8574) is [here](https://github.com/karunadheera/lcdpcf8574).

Comment: My guess is digitalWrite/Read is not going via the PCF8574

Comment: Hi @leppie. No error is throwing in the code. When I run I see, ./lcd_pcf8574
PCF8574 LCD start and that's all. Should I call myDigitalRead and myDigitalWrite instead?

Comment: Why would you expect an error thrown in the code? IMO, I would remove wiringPi as that seems the source of the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I went to basic I2C methods in wiringPi. Now LCD seems identifying my commands. Updated code is at http://karunadheera.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/lcd_pcf85741.c I think I'm getting somewhere now. :-)

Comment: However still I could not get the character appear on the LCD. May be some usleep() between commands will help. Will try later today.

Comment: Hi @leppie, I got it working finally after few hours of refactoring. The updated code is at http://karunadheera.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/lcd_pcf8574.c Can I post this as an answer?

Comment: Sure, self answers are the best :)

Comment: Hi @leppie, can I accept the answer as correct, myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latch command "lcd_probe" was not being called as required by the HD44780. The older code didn't have this properly implemented.

By calling these commands correctly the LCD started working.

I have added few more features such as handling signal SIGINT (=Ctrl + c on keyboard).

Thanks to @leppie I got encouraged to look back into the code and identify the issue. :-)

UPDATE:
I wrote a library based on C++ which can even used by Python. Download and try it out. https://github.com/karunadheera/lcdpcf8574

Comment: @leppie, now my idea is to configure this code as an installable library for raspberry pi. That should be able to be called by anyone from Python or C. Any good guide to refer to? Thanks!